# How to estimate variance when measuring fluctuating variable that never settles?

Tags: variance, measurement-error, measurement

I am supposed the investigate viscosity related phenomena in water flow through a horizontal pipe, connected to a water tank at one end, and with clear opening on the other. Mounted in the middle is perpendicularly protruding vertical manometer tube with height markings.

Depending on the pressure induced by internal forces in the fluid, water level in the manometer tube will change. Problem is (and it's indeed what I'm supposed to observe) that under certain conditions, flow will chaotically go back and forth between being turbulent and laminar, which causes the water level in the manometer tube to constantly fluctuate and never settle on one value that could be used in the further analysis. **What would be a good estimate of 'mean water level' and it's error?**

When quantifying the error in measuring / estimating a variable, I usually refer to its variance (since it's straightforward to estimate reliably and model it's propagation), but that is always when I can take many measurements, each with clearly defined value. In this case, water level will have changed before I could even read it. It never settles, and doesn't oscillate in any nice, predictable way (harmonic etc.).

Most I can do without explicitly recording it and working with the footage is to note the bounds which constrain the fluctuations. I found that other people who previously worked on this assignment simply used $\sigma = $ upper bound - lower bound (and got away with it) but I would like to use a more proper method, and be able to justify it, so that I can give a reasonable estimate of variance of the variables derived from the water level (mostly by multiplying it and taking it's powers).

Comment: It might help if you could show some manometer height versus time data, ideally surrounding a transition between laminar and turbulent flow. The variance in the turbulent regime might depend on the width of the time window you use to calculate the mean and variance. Remember that there's a difference between the instrumental noise contributing to variance in the laminar regime and the (potentially deterministic) variability arising from chaotic dynamics in turbulence.